# Is there a bi-Hölder Weierstrass-type embedding of the circle into some Euclidean space?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, fractals, metric-embeddings

We say that $\Phi\colon S^1\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is an $\alpha$-bi-Hölder embedding if there are constants $c_1,c_2>0$, such that
$$c_1\leq \frac{\|\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)\|}{d(x,y)^\alpha}\leq c_2,$$
where $d$ is the standard distance on the unit circle $S_1$.

For a Lipschitz function $\varphi\colon S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ and a pair of numbers $b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\tfrac1b<\lambda<1$, one can define the associated Weierstrass-type function $W_{\lambda,b}^\varphi\colon S^1\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$W_{\lambda,b}^\varphi(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lambda^k\varphi(b^kx).$$
It is well known that $W_{\lambda,b}^{\varphi}$ is $\alpha$-Hölder for $\alpha=-\frac{\log \lambda}{\log b}$

My question is the following: Given $b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\tfrac1b<\lambda<1$, does there exist $d\in\mathbb{N}$ and a collection $\{\varphi_i\colon S^1\to\mathbb{R}\}_{i=1}^d$ of Lipschitz functions, such that the map $\Phi\colon S^1\to\mathbb{R}^d$ defined by
$$\Phi(x)=(W_{\lambda,b}^{\varphi_1}(x),W_{\lambda,b}^{\varphi_2}(x),\ldots,W_{\lambda,b}^{\varphi_d}(x))$$
is an $\alpha$-bi-Hölder embedding for $\alpha=-\frac{\log\lambda}{\log b}$.